# signed to positive near-perfect hash

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, hash, long-integer, perfect-hash

I have an integer type, say `long`, whose values are between `Long.MIN_VALUE = 0x80...0` (-2^63) and `Long.MAX_VALUE = 0x7f...f` (2^63 - 1). I want to hash it with ~50% collision to a positive integer of the same type (i.e. between 1 and `Long.MAX_VALUE`) in a clean and efficient manner.

My first attempts were something like:

- `Math.abs(x) + 1`
- `(x & Long.MAX_VALUE) + 1`

but those and similar approaches always have problems with certain values, i.e. when `x` is `0` / `Long.MIN_VALUE` / `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Of course, the naive solution is to use 2 if statements, but I'm looking for something cleaner / shorter / faster. Any ideas?

Note: Assume that I'm working in Java where there is no implicit conversion to boolean and shift semantics is defined.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest approach is to zero the sign bit and then map zero to some other value:

```
Long y = x & Long.MAX_VALUE;
return (y == 0)? 42: y;
```

This is simple, uses only one if/ternary operator, and gives ~50% collision rate on average. There is one disadvantage: it maps 4 different values (0, 42, MIN_VALUE, MIN_VALUE+42) to one value (42). So for this value we have 75% collisions, while for other values - exactly 50%.

It may be preferable to distribute collisions more evenly:

```
return (x == 0)? 42: (x == Long.MIN_VALUE) ? 142: x & Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

This code gives 67% collisions for 2 values and 50% for other values. You cannot distribute collisions more evenly, but it is possible to choose these 2 most colliding values. Disadvantage is that this code uses two ifs/ternary operators.

It is possible to avoid 75% collisions on single value while using only one if/ternary operator:

```
Long y = x & Long.MAX_VALUE;
return (y == 0)? 42 - (x >> 7): y;
```

This code gives 67% collisions for 2 values and 50% collisions for other values. There is less freedom choosing these most colliding values: 0 maps to 42 (and you can choose almost any value instead); MIN_VALUE maps to `42 - (MIN_VALUE >> 7)` (and you can shift MIN_VALUE by any value from 1 to 63, only make sure that `A - (MIN_VALUE >> B)` does not overflow).

---

It is possible to get the same result (67% collisions for 2 values and 50% collisions for other values) without conditional operators (but with more complicated code):

```
Long y = x - 1 - ((x >> 63) << 1);
Long z = y + 1 + (y >> 63);
return z & Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

This gives 67% collisions for values '1' and 'MAX_VALUE'. If it is more convenient to get most collisions for some other values, just apply this algorithm to `x + A`, where 'A' is any number.

An improved variant of this solution:

```
Long y = x + 1 + ((x >> 63) << 1);
Long z = y - (y >> 63);
return z & Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: Variation, if you have faith in the optimizer: `return (abs(x) == 0) ? 42 : abs(x)`

Comment: @RichardSitze: there is a little problem with Math.abs(). It gives negative result for Long.MIN_VALUE. But OP needs a positive integer.

Comment: return (Math.abs(x) < 1) ? 42 : Math.abs(x)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to collapse all values into the positive space, why not just zero the sign bit?

You can do this with a single bitwise op by taking advantage of the fact that MAX_VALUE is just a zero sign bit followed by ones e.g.

```
int positive = value & Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Or for longs:

```
long positive = value & Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

If you want a "better" hash with pseudo-random qualities, you probably want to pss the value through another hash function first. My favourite fast hashes are the [XORshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) family by George Marsaglia. These have the nice property that they map the entire int / long number space perfectly onto itself, so you will still get exactly 50% collisions after zeroing the sign bit.

Here's a quick XORshift implementation in Java:

```
public static final long xorShift64(long a) {
    a ^= (a << 21);
    a ^= (a >>> 35);
    a ^= (a << 4);
    return a;
}

public static final int xorShift32(int a) {
    a ^= (a << 13);
    a ^= (a >>> 17);
    a ^= (a << 5);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: This collapses to non-negative space, I need to collapse to positive.

Answer (score 1):

From the information theoretic view, you have `2^64` values to map into `2^63-1` values.

As such, mapping is trivial with the modulus operator, since it always has a non-negative result:

```
y = 1 + x % 0x7fffffffffffffff;  // the constant is 2^63-1
```

This could be pretty expensive, so what else is possible?

The simple math `2^64 = 2 * (2^63 - 1)  + 2` says we will have two source values mapping to one target value except in two special cases, where three will go to one.  Think of these as two special 64-bit values, call them `x1` and `x2`, that each share a target with two other source values.  In the `mod` expression above, this occurs by "wrapping".  The target values `y=2^31-2` and `y=2^31-3` have three mappings.  All others have two. Since we have to use something more complex than `mod` anyway, let's seek a way to map the special values wherever we like at low cost

For illustration let's work with mapping a 4-bit signed int `x` in [-8..7] to `y` in [1..7], rather than the 64-bit space.

An easy course is to have `x` values in [1..7] map to themselves, then the problem reduces to mapping `x` in [-8..0] to `y` in [1..7].  Note there are 9 source values here and only 7 targets as discussed above.

There are obviously many strategies.  At this point you can probably see a gazzilion.  I'll describe only one that's particularly simple.

Let `y = 1 - x` for all values except special cases `x1 == -8` and `x2 == -7`.  The whole hash function thus becomes

```
y = x <= -7 ? S(x) : x <= 0 ? 1 - x : x;
```

Here `S(x)` is a simple function that says where `x1` and `x2` are mapped. Choose `S` based on what you know about the data. For example if you think high target values are unlikely, map them to 6 and 7 with `S(x) = -1 - x`.

The final mapping is:

```
-8: 7    -7: 6    -6: 7    -5: 6    -4: 5    -3: 4    -2: 3    -1: 2
 0: 1     1: 1     2: 2     3: 3     4: 4     5: 5     6: 6     7: 7
```

Taking this logic up to the 64-bit space, you'd have

```
y = (x <= Long.MIN_VALUE + 1) ? -1 - x : x <= 0 ? 1 - x : x;
```

Many other kinds of tuning are possible within this framework.

Comment: You and I think an awful lot alike... I already had numbers [-8..7] in a list to play with. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for the most simple, yet not totally time wasting version:

```
public static long postiveHash(final long hash) {
    final long result = hash & Long.MAX_VALUE;
    return (result != 0) ? result : (hash == 0 ? 1 : 2);
}
```

This implementation pays one conditional operation for all but *two* possible inputs: 0 and MIN_VALUE. Those two are assigned different value mappings with the second condition. I doubt you get a better combination of (code) simplicity and (computational) complexity.

Of course if you can live with a worse distribution, it gets *a lot simpler*. By restricting the space to 1/4 instead of to 1/2 -1 you can get:

```
public static long badDistribution(final long hash) {
    return (hash & -4) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is positive, it probably can be used directly, else, invert all bits:

```
x >= 0 ? hash = x : hash = x ^ Long.MIN_VALUE
```

However, you should scramble this value a bit more if the values of `x` are correlated (meaning: similar objects produce similar values for `x`), maybe with

```
hash = a * (hash + b) % (Long.MAX_VALUE) + 1
```

for some positive constants `a` and `b`, where `a` should be quite large and `b` prevents that `0` is always mapped to `1`. This also maps the whole thing to [1,Long.MAX_VALUE] instead of [0,Long.MAX_VALUE]. By altering the values for `a` and `b` you could also implement more complex hash functionalities like [cooko hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing), that needs two different hash functions.

Such a solution should definitely be preferred instead of one that delivers "strange collision distribution" for the same values each time it is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any conditionals and in a single expression by using the unsigned shift operator:

```
public static int makePositive(int x) {
  return (x >>> 1) + (~x >>> 31);
}
```

Comment: Probably the best way to avoid conditionals. If collapsing 4 values into one is not desirable, this may be preprocessed by `x += x >>> 31`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you have a long and want to hash it to an int?

You could do...

```
(int) x                 // This results in a meaningless number, but it works
(int) (x & 0xffffffffl) // This will give you just the low order bits
(int) (x >> 32)         // This will give you just the high order bits
((Long) x).hashcode()   // This is the high and low order bits XORed together
```

If you want to keep a long you could do...

```
x & 0x7fffffffffffffffl // This will just ignore the sign, Long.MIN_VALUE -> 0
x & Long.MAX_VALUE      // Should be the same I think
```

If getting a 0 is no good...

```
x & 0x7ffffffffffffffel + 1 // This has a 75% collision rate.
```

Just thinking out loud...

```
((x & Long.MAX_VALUE) << 1) + 1 // I think this is also 75%
```

I think you're going to need to either be ok with 75% or get a little ugly:

```
(x > 0) ? x : (x < 0) ? x & Long.MAX_VALUE : 7
```

Comment: No, the hash codomain is long again - but it must be > 0. I'll update the post to make it more precise.

Comment: Note that in the "ugly" example 0 collides with 7.

Comment: The "ugly" example maps MIN_VALUE to 0. And getting 0 is no good.

Answer (score 0):

This seems the simplest of all:

```
(x % Long.MAX_VALUE) + 1
```

I would be interested in speed comparisons of all the methods given.

Answer (score 0):

Just AND your input value with Long.MAX_VALUE and OR it with 1.  Nothing else needed.

Ex:

```
long hash = (input & Long.MAX_VALUE) | 1;
```

Comment: Good and simple approach. Only problem is, that three very similar values (-1, 0, 1) are always mapped to the same single value (1).

Comment: I think that still more than qualifies for the approximate ~50% collision as stated in the original question, yes?